# Can't connect my Spring Boot Application with my MariaDB Database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mariadb

I am trying to set up a Spring Boot backend with a MariaDB database. I generated a Spring Boot project from https://start.spring.io, I have configured my application.properties in the way I am showing you below and I am also creating an Entity class named User with the @Entity and @Id annotations place over the class definition and the id field of the class. I have also created a MariaDB database called pos2cloud. However, when I execute the application, I can see in the terminal that the connection to the database is established successfully, but the entity tables are never created. Below is my code for the application, as well as the application.properties file.

1. application.properties

   ```
   server.address=0.0.0.0
   server.port=5000
   spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
   spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/pos2cloud
   spring.datasource.username=""
   spring.datasource.password=""
   ```
2. User.java

   ```
    package com.pos2cloud.restservice;

    import javax.persistence.*;

    import java.util.Objects;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="user")
    public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        @Column(name="name")
        private String name;
        @Column(name="email")
        private String email;

        public User(){}

        public User(String name, String email){
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (o == this)
                return true;
            if (!(o instanceof User)) {
                return false;
            }
            User user = (User) o;
            return Objects.equals(id, user.id) && Objects.equals(name, user.name) && 
                Objects.equals(email, user.email);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(id, name, email);
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{" +
                " id='" + getId() + "'" +
                ", name='" + getName() + "'" +
                ", email='" + getEmail() + "'" +
           "}";
        }  
    }
   ```
3. RestServiceApplication.java

   ```
    package com.pos2cloud.restservice;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class RestServiceApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(RestServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
   ```

}

The terminal output is the following:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.pos2cloud:rest-service >---------------------
[INFO] Building rest-service 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.3:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ rest- 
service >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ rest-service ---
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ rest-service ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /home/ubuntu/pos2cloud/rest-service/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.3.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ rest- 
service ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/ubuntu/pos2cloud/rest- 
service/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ rest-service 
---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/ubuntu/pos2cloud/rest-service/target/test- 
classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.3:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ rest- 
service <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.3:run (default-cli) @ rest-service ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.3)

2023-03-02T19:54:02.492Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] 
c.p.restservice.RestServiceApplication   : Starting RestServiceApplication using Java 
17.0.5 with PID 363131 (/home/ubuntu/pos2cloud/rest-service/target/classes started by 
ubuntu in /home/ubuntu/pos2cloud/rest-service)
2023-03-02T19:54:02.497Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] 
c.p.restservice.RestServiceApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 
default profile: "default"
2023-03-02T19:54:03.008Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in 
DEFAULT mode.
2023-03-02T19:54:03.027Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 
11 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-03-02T19:54:03.505Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] 
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 5000 (http)
2023-03-02T19:54:03.515Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] 
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-03-02T19:54:03.515Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] 
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache 
Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-03-02T19:54:03.600Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat]. 
[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-03-02T19:54:03.602Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] 
w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization 
completed in 1059 ms
2023-03-02T19:54:03.737Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] 
o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo 
[name: default]
2023-03-02T19:54:03.777Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    
: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-03-02T19:54:03.928Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] 
o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations 
{5.1.2.Final}
2023-03-02T19:54:04.016Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-03-02T19:54:04.082Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection 
org.mariadb.jdbc.Connection@58dad04a
2023-03-02T19:54:04.096Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-03-02T19:54:04.114Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              
: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect
2023-03-02T19:54:04.115Z  WARN 363131 --- [           main]
o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: 
[org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-03-02T19:54:04.367Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] 
j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for 
persistence unit 'default'
2023-03-02T19:54:04.400Z  WARN 363131 --- [           main] 
JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by 
default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly 
configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-03-02T19:54:04.711Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] 
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 5000 (http) with 
context path ''
2023-03-02T19:54:04.720Z  INFO 363131 --- [           main] 
c.p.restservice.RestServiceApplication   : Started RestServiceApplication in 2.565 
seconds (process running for 2.852)
```

Can someone please give an explanation why is this happening and give me some feedback how I can make it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

1. to remove
   **spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update**
   OR
2. to remove
   **spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true**
   and I would add
   **logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG**

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Comment: I tried removing each of them and still no change in the DB.